# Using HTML from webserver in Thunderbird email signature

Tags: thunderbird, email-signature

I want to insert html from a webserver as an email signature, but the UI doesn't allow it directly. I tried creating a local HTML with an iframe that sources the remote content, but thunderbird isn't referencing it.

There is a reasonable chance this is designed for security, but is a little irritating.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Essentially I tried including:

```
<iframe src="<webserver URL>"/>
```

But it didn't take it.

Comment: Dynamically create an image on your server, and reference that. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35253972

Comment: You can use an HTML signature from a file which includes links, but Thunderbird won't follow a link.